# Semantic UI React getting input value by input name

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is there a way to get a semantic ui react input's value by name in React? For example, I have the following code:

```
ids.map((id) => <>
    <Input name={id}></Input>
</>
)
<Button onClick={handleSubmit}></Button>
```

Where I want handlesubmit to go through the array of ids, and get the input's value by its id.

Answer (score 0):

```
const HandleSumbit = (event, {name}) => console.log(name);
```

Change `{name}` for `{event}` to see element input with attributes.